# rotating vector based on plane normal

Tags: geometry, 3d

This is probably very basic, but here is a drawing of what I'm trying to achieve :

[image: img]

Explanation : Those are 3D normalized vectors and I'm trying to change *v1* to *v1'* based on *vn*.

As shown in the drawing, if *vn* is the "up vector" (0, 0, 1) in my case, *v1* should be equal to *v1'*

Am I missing information ? What is the simplest way to do this ?